# How to find Unique records (in all columns) in a table as mentioned below criteria with SQL or Python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Consider a Table1 having two columns :col1 and col2

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | A |
| C | D |
| E | F |
| F | E |

How can we find final output as ( we have to find unique records) :

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| C | D |
| E | F |

**** OR ****

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| B | A |
| C | D |
| F | E |

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select col1, col2
from t
where col1 < col2 or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.col1 = t.col2 and t2.col2 = t.col1
                 );
```

That is, select all rows where `col1 < col2`.  Or, select all rows where no such row exists.

Comment: @DeepanshiSet Please, check [A Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). If you think this answer is good enough, it helped you to resolve the issue, you can accept it and/or optionally upvote it as the most relevant and helpful. This helps future readers to find at least the way to solve similar problem and shows others that this question have helpful answer with no need to dig into comments

Answer (score 0):

This snippet cannot find all possible "unique" sets, but it can find at least one. Hope it can fit your current problem.

```
table = [['A', 'B'],
         ['B', 'A'],
         ['C', 'D'],
         ['E', 'F'],
         ['F', 'E']]
unique_set = set()
for row in table:
    tmp = frozenset(row)
    if tmp not in unique_set:
        unique_set.add(tmp)

print(unique_set)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like pythonic solutions, here is my way:

df

```
  col1  col2
0   A   B
1   B   A
2   C   D
3   E   F
4   F   E
```

create new column

```
df['test'] = [sorted(x) for x in list(zip(df['col1'],df['col2']))]
```

output:

```
  col1  col2  test
0   A   B   [A, B]
1   B   A   [A, B]
2   C   D   [C, D]
3   E   F   [E, F]
4   F   E   [E, F]
```

remove duplicates and get the index:

```
idx = df['test'].astype(str).drop_duplicates().index
```

new dataframe:

```
del df['test']
df.loc[idx]
```

.

```
  col1  col2
0   A   B
2   C   D
3   E   F
```